# multiple set with where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I want to update value for one column by using set and where.

I made query like

```
update Students set Studentid =case 
when Studentid=1  then class= 10 
when studentid = 3 then class=9
when studentid=2 and studentid =4 then class=8 
End
```

but i guess it is not working. Please help me with it.

Comment: Can you describe what you want to achieve with above query? Query is anyway looking incorrect.

Comment: So is it the `studentid` or the `class` yopu want to change?

Comment: And do you think any record will match the criteria `studentid=2 and studentid =4`? A record's `studentid` can *either* be 2 *or* 4 (or another value), not 2 and 4 at the same time. Hence: `studentid=2 or studentid =4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to say:

```
UPDATE Students
SET class = CASE WHEN Studentid = 1       THEN 10
                 WHEN Studentid = 3       THEN 9
                 WHEN Studentid IN (2, 4) THEN 8 END
WHERE Studentid IN (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

I added a `WHERE` clause to ensure that we only touch a record which would actually be affected by the update logic.

Comment: this is perfect. Thank you